# GLSL, combining 2D and 3D textures

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

I am trying to blend a 3D texture with a 2D one to make a terrain. The 3D texture has moss, sand, snow and the like, interpolated to enhance the illusion of heights. The 2D texture currently only has an orange line across meant to be a "road". This is my fragment shader:

```
# version 420

uniform sampler3D mainTexture;
uniform sampler2D roadTexture;

void main() {
    vec4 diffuse3D = texture3D(mainTexture, gl_TexCoord[0].stp);
    vec4 diffuse2D = texture2D(roadTexture, gl_TexCoord[1].st);
    // Yes, I am aware I am only returning the 2D texture value
    // However this is for testing purposes only
    // Doing gl_FragColor = diffuse3D + diffuse2D;
    // Or any other operation returns the 3D texture only
    gl_FragColor = diffuse2D; 
}
```

And this is my drawing call:

```
void Terrain::Draw() {

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(glm::vec3), &v[0].x);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY); 
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(glm::vec3), &n[0].x); 

    s.enable(); // simple glUseProgram call within my Shader object

    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, id_texture);
    s.setSampler("mainTexture",0); // Calls to glGetUniformLocation and glUniform1i
    glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(glm::vec3), &t[0].x);

    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_texture_road);
    s.setSampler("roadTexture",1); // Same as above
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(glm::vec2), &t2[0].x);

    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(scalex,scaley,scalez);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizei, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, index);
    glPopMatrix();

    s.disable(); // glUseProgram(0)

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY); 
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); 
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Here is the code for my `setSampler()` method:

```
void Shader::setSampler(std::string name, GLint value)
{
    GLuint loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, name.c_str());
    if (loc>0)
    {
        glUniform1i(loc, value); 
    }
}
```

The result is a solid black color upon the whole terrain. I have sadly been unable to find information on sampler3D, but the diffuse3D variable in my fragment shader does compute to the correct texture, and my texture coordinates for the 2D texture are being correcly sent to the fragment shader (I know this because I used them to color the terrain for testing and got a smooth gradinent from green to red, what you would expect using only the first 2 coordinates). I also checked the values passed to my `setSampler()` method and I do get the 0 and 1, and the 1 and 2 locations corresponding to them.

All of the help I can find on this issue is around the vicinity of the advice provided [here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/163092-Passing-Multiple-Textures-from-OpenGL-to-GLSL-shader), which I have already implemented).

Can anybody assist?

**EDIT:** So, just for kicks, I swapped my texture units so the 2D texture became unit 0 and the 3D became unit 1. Now only the 2D texture is rendered. But my texture units are passed correctly (at least in appearence) to the shader. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved this problem. Apprently you still need `glActiveTexture()` in addition to `glClientActiveTexture()`. This was the code that worked, for anyone who gets the same problem:

```
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, id_texture);
s.setSampler("mainTexture",0); // Calls to glGetUniformLocation and glUniform1i
glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(glm::vec3), &t[0].x);

glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_texture_road);
s.setSampler("roadTexture",1); // Same as above
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(glm::vec2), &t2[0].x);

// Drawing Calls

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY); 
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); 
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); 
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
vec4 diffuse3D = texture3D(mainTexture, gl_TexCoord[0].stp);
vec4 diffuse2D = texture2D(roadTexture, gl_TexCoord[1].st);
gl_FragColor = diffuse2D;
```

Let's pretend that this wasn't using shaders. Let's pretend you were just writing a function in C++ that returns a value.

```
int FuncName(int val1, int val2)
{
  int test1 = Compute(val1);
  int test2 = Compute(val2);
  return test2;
}
```

What will this function return? Obviously, it returns `Compute(val2)`, *completely ignoring* the value of `test1`. It won't magically combine `test1` and `test2`. They're separate values, and therefore, they remain separate unless you explicitly combine them.

Just like your fragment shader.

Shaders aren't magic; they're programming. They only do what you *tell* them to. So if you say, "get a value from a texture and then don't do anything with it", it will dutifully do exactly that. Though odds are good that the compiler will optimize out the texture fetch entirely.

If you want a "blend" of two textures, you must *blend them*. You must fetch from each texture, then use *both values* to compute a new color.

How exactly you do that depends *entirely* on you. Maybe your 2D texture has some alpha that represents how much of the 2D texture to show. I don't know; you didn't describe what your texture looks like or how exactly you plan to show the road in some places and not in others.

Comment: Perhaps should have pasted another piece of code...Multiplying or adding both values doesn't work either. When I try to blend them I only get the 3D texture

Answer (score 1):

the reason you get a black color is simply that you don't set proper uniform variables.

```
# version 420

uniform sampler3D mainTexture;
uniform sampler2D roadTexture;

void main() {
    vec4 diffuse3D = texture3D(mainTexture, gl_TexCoord[0].stp);
    vec4 diffuse2D = texture2D(roadTexture, gl_TexCoord[1].st);
    gl_FragColor = diffuse2D;
}
```

what this shader is doing, is looking up the value of 'roadTexture' and displaying it. unfortunately, it has no clue which texture unit 'roadTexture' is currently bound to, and thus will acess texture unit 0, where your 3d texture is bound - so your're trying to access a 3d texture with 2d texcoords, which may well return all black. you'll need to query the uniform locations of your textures with `glGetUniformLocation` and then set them to the correct texture units ( 0/1, respectively ) with `glUniform1i`.

EDIT: also, you're using deprecated functionality, so your shader version directive should be changed to `#version 420 compatibility` - the default is `core`

Comment: This is precisely what I do at `s.setSampler("mainTexture",0);` and `s.setSampler("roadTexture",1);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);` again after you have made the second texture unit active with `glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);`

from http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml

> enabling and disabling GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY affects the active client texture unit.

Comment: Just tried this unsuccessfully. Still a good thing to know. I'll update my code above.

Comment: Sorry - just re-read your question and it looks like texture coordinates were never the problem. Afraid I'm stumped!